# Get all Column of foreign key table along with main table column in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to get list of all **subjects** for all **students**(Subject list within student list).

**Subject** table(SubjectPk,StudentId,SubjectName,Description,AddedOn,AddedBy) has many subject for the single student.

**I have tried this: No Luck**

```
     var data = (from st in db.Student                     
                       join sub in db.Subject on st.StudentId equals  sub.st.StudentId into subjectsList

                       select new StudentModel
                       {
                           Name = st.Name,
               Class= st.Class,
               RollNo = st.RollNo,
                           SubjectList = subjectsList //public ILIst<Subject> SubjectList {get;set;}
                       }).ToList();
```

**and this : No Luck**

```
var data = (from st in db.Student                     
                       select new StudentModel
                       {
                           Name = st.Name,
               Class= st.Class,
               RollNo = st.RollNo,
                           SubjectList = db.Subject.where(s.StudentId == st.StudentId).ToList()

                       }).ToList();
```

and

```
var data = (from st in db.Student                     
                   let subjectsList = db.Subject.where(s.StudentId == st.StudentId).ToList()

                   select new StudentModel
                   {
                       Name = st.Name,
           Class= st.Class,
           RollNo = st.RollNo,
                       SubjectList = subjectsList 
                   }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this looks like a Many to many relationship between Student and Subject, ideally you should have a different table that reference both students and subjects. so you should have something like this:

```
public class Student{
   public int Id{get; set;}
   public string StudentName{get; set;}
   public IList<StudentsSubjects> Subjects{get; set;}
   // other properties
}

public class Subject{
   public int Id{get; set;}
   public string SubjectTitle{get; set;}
   public IList<StudentsSubjects> Students{get; set;}
   // other properties
}

public class StudentsSubjects{
  public int Id{get; set;}
  public int StudentId{get; set;}
  public int SubjectId{get; set;}
  public DateTime DateAdded{get; set;}
}
```

Then if you are using entity framework you do

```
data = db.Student.Include(s => s.Subjects).ToList()
```

then use a foreach loop and get the data you want.

Comment: Yes you are right but I am not using the entity framework sadly :(.

Comment: are you trying to get the subjects only?

Comment: No i like to get the     st.Name,         st.Class,           st.RollNo and                   subjectsList

Answer (score 0):

Your first attempt looks ok except that i removed sub.st.StudentId to sub.StudentId

```
 var data = (from st in db.Student                     
                   join sub in db.Subject on st.StudentId equals 
                   sub.StudentId into subjectsList

                   select new StudentModel
                   {
                       Name = st.Name,
           Class= st.Class,
           RollNo = st.RollNo,
                       SubjectList = subjectsList //public ILIst<Subject> SubjectList {get;set;}
                   }).ToList();
```

Comment: Actually it will retrieve only one column of the subject table and i need all, and that can be achieved using join in simple way

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add `ToList()` for subjectList. Please try this:

```
 var data = (from st in db.Student                     
             join sub in db.Subject on st.StudentId equals  sub.st.StudentId into subjectsList
             select new StudentModel
             {
                 Name = st.Name,
                 Class= st.Class,
                 RollNo = st.RollNo,
                 SubjectList = subjectsList.ToList() //public ILIst<Subject> SubjectList {get;set;}
             }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please check the below code it's working

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var employees = new List<Employees>() {
                new Employees(){ Id = 1,CompanyName="Google",EmpCode="12345", EmployeeName="Ravindra"},
                new Employees(){ Id = 2,CompanyName="Microsoft",EmpCode="123456", EmployeeName="Vishal"},
                new Employees(){ Id = 3,CompanyName="IBM",EmpCode="123457", EmployeeName="Kishore"},
                new Employees(){ Id = 4,CompanyName="Capgemini",EmpCode="123458", EmployeeName="Amit"}
            };
        var technologies = new List<Technology>()
        {
            new Technology(){EmployeeId=1,TechnologyName="Data Structure"},
            new Technology(){EmployeeId=1,TechnologyName="Dotnet 6"},
            new Technology(){EmployeeId=1,TechnologyName="SQL"},
            new Technology(){EmployeeId=1,TechnologyName="Azure"},
            new Technology(){EmployeeId=1,TechnologyName="React"},
            new Technology(){EmployeeId=1,TechnologyName="Angular"},
            new Technology(){EmployeeId=2,TechnologyName="Dotnet 1"},
            new Technology(){EmployeeId=2,TechnologyName="Dotnet 2"},
            new Technology(){EmployeeId=2,TechnologyName="Dotnet 3"},
            new Technology(){EmployeeId=2,TechnologyName="Dotnet 4"},
            new Technology(){EmployeeId=2,TechnologyName="Dotnet 5"},
            new Technology(){EmployeeId=2,TechnologyName="Dotnet 6"},
            new Technology(){EmployeeId=2,TechnologyName="Dotnet 7"},
            new Technology(){EmployeeId=2,TechnologyName="Dotnet 8"},
            new Technology(){EmployeeId=2,TechnologyName="Development"},
            new Technology(){EmployeeId=3,TechnologyName="DAA"},
            new Technology(){EmployeeId=4,TechnologyName="Math"},
            new Technology(){EmployeeId=5,TechnologyName="English"}
        };

        var result = (from st in employees
                      select new ShowModel
                      {
                          EmployeeName = st.EmployeeName,
                          CompanyName = st.CompanyName,
                          EmpCode = st.EmpCode,
                          TechnologyList = technologies.Where(x => x.EmployeeId == st.Id).ToList()
                      }).ToList();

        foreach (var final in result)
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} | Class: {1} | RollNo: {2} | TechnologyList Count: {3} ", final.EmployeeName, final.CompanyName, final.EmpCode, final.TechnologyList.Count);

    }

    public class Employees
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string EmpCode { get; set; }
    }

    public class Technology
    {
        public string TechnologyName { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    }

    public class ShowModel
    {
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string EmpCode { get; set; }
        public IList<Technology> TechnologyList { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).